# java.lang.NullPointerException Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been suffering from this problem 2 days and i can't solve it

I have this code

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
 private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
 //Android Layout

 private CircleImageView mDisplayImage;
 private TextView mName;
 private TextView mStatus;
 private Button mStatusBtn;
 private Button mImageBtn;
 private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

 // Storage Firebase
 private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

     mDisplayImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_image);
     mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_name);
     mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_status);
     mStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_status_btn);
     mImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_image_btn);
     mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

     String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();
     mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);
     mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);
     mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            final String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
            String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
            mName.setText(name);
            mStatus.setText(status);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
 }
}
```

In my log i got this problem

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.pc.newchatj, PID: 724
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.pc.newchatj.SettingsActivity$1.onDataChange(SettingsActivity.java:74)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Here is my FirebaseDatabase screen

[image]

Can any onw help please , Thanks !!!

Comment: This means that `.getValue()` on one of the properties inside the `onDataChange` function is returning null.

Comment: What does your firebase database structure look like?

Comment: String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid() - Try printing this value to your log and see what you get

Comment: Add your database structure because apparently something is wrong with your referencing to your database.

Comment: @MartinLund i added the picture of my Firebase screen

Comment: @MartinLund I tried printing the String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid() by a toast and it prints it just fine

Comment: Which line is line 74?

Comment: @Mark String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

Comment: I notice quotes around your variables in your firebase screen, it even includes a space at the end which makes me think that you typed that by hand? Is that the case? I'm unfamiliar with firebase.

Comment: Try doing `dataSnapshot.child("\"name \"").getValue().toString()` It looks like certain keys in your User have quotes put around them for some reason.

Comment: @TheWanderer There's a space after `name`, but yes that's what I figure should work aswell.

Comment: @Mark I think OP is setting these values manually, as you said, and not correctly settings keys.

Comment: Yep the " in firebase variables are screwing up your data!

Answer (score 4):

remove the `"` double quotes & `_` spaces from Firebase field names `name` and `status`.

Comment: Looks like there are manually added quotes in the values as well.

Comment: I don't think Firebase puts quotes around anything in the console display.

Comment: I'm also curious how OP is setting the data.If it's done programmatically, that code needs to be fixed.

Comment: @TheWanderer the quotes around string data are correct; just checked.

Comment: @TheWanderer field names and numeric values have no quotes there... strings do.

Comment: No I mean there aren't any end-quotes for the values.

Comment: Thats  a firebase GUI thing, when the string gets too "long" it wont show the end quote, they are still there

Comment: @MartinLund "default" is a pretty short string.

Comment: @TheWanderer it is, but it will still automatically hide it, i dont know when it does, but if you try to input some data in firebase you can see when it does,

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Martin answer, you can also do this

```
String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
```

instead of this

```
String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
```

Also, always make sure that your reference is matching exactly your data at your Firebase Console and always use

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists()){....}
```

before getting any results, so you can catch any problems there

for example

```
    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
    String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                final String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                mName.setText(name);
                mStatus.setText(status);

    }
  ...
```